How do I backup only changed files on an external hard drive?
So I have an external HD and I want to have a backup of it on another external HD.
The thing is that I am always cleaning up, deleting, renaming, organizing and editing things on that HD.
How can I make a backup that will keep up with those changes?
When I say backup I mean an exact copy with the exact same set of files in the exact same layout not an archival copy that could, for example, consist of one big file storing all the data.
I need a reliable method, and something well documented or a step by step instruction manual.
Thanks

This question is similar to: Installing Timeshift backup on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Will also work on earlier versions of Ubuntu.

By ‘backup’, do you mean an exact copy with the exact same set of files in the exact same layout, or an archival copy that could, for example, consist of one big file storing all the data?

I believe this question is different because I am asking for how/what program or method to use to get the backup I want/need.  The other link tells you how to install timeshift.  As a result of that I will now consider and research timeshift along with the other answers given below.
Also I edited the question to include my exact definition of backup.

I’ve put a comment for you under the answer by Stormlord.

The app you need is called rsync and it's in the system.
Using it with the following parameters will give you a complete backup of the source files and folders the first time and incremental backups from then on. It will check for updated, moved or added files and backup those ones only.
rsync -av --delete '/source folder/' '/backup folder/'

If you use the parameter --delete, it will be used by rsync whenever you delete files or folders inside the source folder so that rsync removes them from the backup folder too in order to make it identical to the source folder. If you ommit it, rsync will add or replace files / folders only, in the backup folder, without deleting anything.
rsync --help

will give you a complete list of the usable parameters.

--delete will not do incremental backups. It'll only keep one copy, the latest one. Incremental backups would be a full backup and the delta changes since each increment. Differential backups store the difference between the full backup and the current version. This terminology is standardized.

@graham - The main thing you need to decide is if you want deleted files from your system also to delete from your ‘backup’ when you invoke rsync. I deliberately don’t - because I want my backup to allow me to restore accidentally deleted files.  I use rsync -auv which doesn’t delete anything from the backup. The downside is that nothing is deleted (automatically) from the backup but I want the safety of knowing I can restore a deleted file. Of course, any rsync command could result in a file being overwritten by an empty / corrupted file, but the risk is lower.

@Will I think you tagged me as opposed to qwr but to answer your comment, I suggested using LuckyBackup in my answer and that app provides the ability to indicate the number of snapshots to retain which woould solve that issue for you.

@graham - sorry, you’re right, I didn’t mean to tag you, I meant to draw attention to the OP.

A GUI version of rsync is available by downloading LuckyBackup from the App Centre.

This is much more intuitive in its use than the non GUI version rsync.

luckyBackup is an application that backs-up and/or synchronizes any
directories with the power of rsync. Its main features are: backup,
safety, synchronization, exclude/only include options, allows custom
rsync options, remote connections, restore and dry-run operations,
scheduling, profiles and command line mode.
It is simple to use, fast (transfers over only changes made and not
all data), safe (keeps your data safe by checking all declared
directories before proceeding in any data manipulation ), reliable and
fully customizable.

It is also quite useful in being able to see what instructions are being generated by the app and to copy them or add further options if required adding to the flexibility.
A guide on how to make a backup on Linux using LuckyBackup can be found here which includes helpful screenshots explaining the whole process in easy to follow steps as requested by the OP.

Another solution is to use BorgBackup. BorgBackup has several advantages over rsync for backups. You can save many snapshots, which is useful if e.g. you realise that you need a file that you accidentally deleted months ago.
It automatically only backs up what has changed in your selected directories since your last backup.
It is primarily a CLI application but there are some nice GUI interfaces such as Vorta and Pika Backup.

I'd recommend Kopia, which does basically the same thing - also comes in a GUI variant.
